# Why does the Federation require a rental agreement?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-deep-space-nine

Why does the Federation act as landlord on Deep Space 9? Sisko threatens to collect five years of back rent from Quark in season 4 episode 16, "The Bar Association," as well as power and repair fees. First, shouldn't this be the Bajoran government?  And second, what exactly would a cashless society like the Federation be collecting rent for?

Answer (score 10):

The Federation is acting *on behalf* of the Bajoran government, and Sisko is appointed to run the station on that basis.

[**Memory Alpha**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9)

> Following the Cardassian withdrawal, the Bajoran Provisional Government petitioned for Federation membership, and also for Starfleet assistance in repairing and maintaining Terok Nor. A complex arrangement was established, in which a Starfleet officer would have overall authority in running the station, while the station remained sovereign Bajoran territory.

The subject of the Feberation being "cashless" has come up before, so I won't go into it here, but Bajor is only a *candidate* for Federation membership, *and* has only just become free from the Cardassian occupation, so it's unlikely to have become post-scarcity, as the Federation supposedly has.

Answer (score -5):

The Federation is fascist, and much like all fascist governments, they need money to help supplement the use of a cashless economic system (if economics are still a thing)

If you don't believe the fact they are fascist, do any google search online, it becomes obvious after you watch a few videos on it.

Comment: can you back that up with some quotes or sources? Just writing it out like this doesn't make your answer very credible.

Comment: It would be viewed as the opposite in fact, and socalist, IMHO